# How do I remove the Unity Splash Screen from my iOS builds?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I have the Unity Plus account which says in it's checklist that one of the things you can do is customise or remove the splash screen but I can't for the life of me find out how.

Comment: You can only [Customize it](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileCustomizeSplashScreen.html)

Comment: You need to go to each devices settings and customize the spash screen,  you can have a static image or an animation,  you can't have none (Just use a black image for 'None')

Comment: Hello. You can customize it in Build Settings > Player Settings > Splash Image. You can check the detailed solution here: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206273385-Why-can-t-I-remove-the-splash-screen-on-iOS-Android- Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> removing iOS splash screen from unity build

The animated image below will show you steps on how to remove it completely. You can also put a custom one from the-same place.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I had signed in wrong and Unity hadn't registered me as a plus user.

Comment: Ok. Well, this may be helpful for others. Happy coding!